# Configuring apache to send user to another site?

Tags: php, apache, googlebot

Is it possible to change this script to send users to another site incase the _escaped_fragment_ is present?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]
```

e.g.
Could the last line be rewritten so it sends the user to

```
http://foo.bar.com/?url=the-full-url-with-hashbangs
```

that is, I want to recreate the "pretty url" from the escaped fragment, and pass that entire url to another site.
That site contains static snapshots that should be returned to the users browser.

[edit]
We are releasing a service that enables javascript sites e.g. angularjs, backbone etc to be indexed by googlebot by hooking in to the _escaped_fragment_ request they make.

see http://crawlr.wombit.se/

I want to be able to give correct examples to the users how to set this up in other environments. we are using this in ASP.NET ourselves.

Comment: Though I am not sure what do you call using word "hashbang". A clear example always better than 1000 words.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. that's impossible.

Just because hashbangs never being sent to server